# I tried installing rstudio on my macbook but i am experiencing an error while loading it, i am using MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015)

Tags: rstudio, rstudio-server, wso2-integration-studio

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2022.12.0+353 "Elsbeth Geranium " (7d165dcf, 2022-12-03) for macOS

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2022.12.0+353 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.1.3 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 1.

Error output:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/t_/gkx37tgd48jf7j4f4hpdg2l40000gp/T/AppTranslocation/585528F6-2F5A-4448-AF68-0BBB2B8A765E/d/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/rsession
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/folders/t_/gkx37tgd48jf7j4f4hpdg2l40000gp/T/AppTranslocation/585528F6-2F5A-4448-AF68-0BBB2B8A765E/d/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib: cannot load 'libssl.1.1.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /private/var/folders/t_/gkx37tgd48jf7j4f4hpdg2l40000gp/T/AppTranslocation/585528F6-2F5A-4448-AF68-0BBB2B8A765E/d/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib: stat() failed with errno=45
    /private/var/folders/t_/gkx37tgd48jf7j4f4hpdg2l40000gp/T/AppTranslocation/585528F6-2F5A-4448-AF68-0BBB2B8A765E/d/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib: cannot load 'libssl.1.1.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /private/var/folders/t_/gkx37tgd48jf7j4f4hpdg2l40000gp/T/AppTranslocation/585528F6-2F5A-4448-AF68-0BBB2B8A765E/d/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib: stat() failed with errno=45
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*Log File*

```
[No logs available]
```

What doesit mean and what can i do

i tried installing the package but keep getting this error

Comment: What version of mac os are you running?

Comment: high sierra 10.13